# CMake with Carbon and Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, cmake, macos-carbon

I'm currently trying to build MyGUI and CMake is telling me that Cocoa and Carbon are missing

Configuring MYGUI 3.2.0
Looking for FREETYPE...
Could NOT find PkgConfig (missing:  PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE) 
CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: ~/Documents/SDK/OgreDependencies/;/Users/david/Documents/SDK/MyGUI_3.2.0/bin/Dependencies;/Users/david/Documents/SDK/MyGUI_3.2.0/Dependencies;/Users/david/Documents/SDK/MyGUI_3.2.0/bin/../Dependencies;/Users/david/Documents/SDK/MyGUI_3.2.0/../Dependencies;/usr/local
Found FREETYPE: /usr/X11R6/lib/libfreetype.dylib
Found OpenGL: /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework
Looking for OIS...
Could NOT find PkgConfig (missing:  PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE) 
Found OIS: /Users/david/Documents/SDK/OgreDependencies/lib/release/libOIS.a
Could NOT find Doxygen (missing:  DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE) 
Looking for Carbon...
Could NOT find PkgConfig (missing:  PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE) 
Could not locate Carbon
Looking for Cocoa...
Could NOT find PkgConfig (missing:  PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE) 
Could not locate Cocoa
Looking for IOKit...
Could NOT find PkgConfig (missing:  PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE) 
Could not locate IOKit
CMake Error at CMake/Utils/MacroLogFeature.cmake:91 (MESSAGE):

---

-- The following REQUIRED packages could NOT be located on your system.

-- Please install them before continuing this software installation.

-- If you are in Windows, try passing -DMYGUI_DEPENDENCIES_DIR=

-- Also check that you buildind with RenderSystem that you need or set
  another with -DMYGUI_RENDERSYSTEM=<1 2 or 3 for Direct3D_9 OGRE or OpenGL>

---

- Carbon: Carbon http://www.apple.com
- Cocoa: Cocoa http://www.apple.com

---

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMake/Dependencies.cmake:108 (MACRO_DISPLAY_FEATURE_LOG)
  CMakeLists.txt:232 (include)

Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

Am I supposed to install them seperately from XCode?

Comment: have you solved your problem? I understand, it was almost 5 years ago, but I have the same problem now and it would be great if you say how to solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, Cocoa and Carbon are base frameworks in OSX, no need to install anything except Xcode.

Your real problem seems to be that you are missing pkg-config on your system. pkg-config is a open source program that makes it easier to find other packages. I suggest that you install it using [homebrew](https://brew.sh/).

When you have installed homebrew you just have to run

```
brew install pkg-config
```

After that you can re-run the CMake script and you should probably have more luck. Just remember to delete the CMakeCache.txt file before you rerun.